# How does jquery regex selector work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I saw the below jquery selector and believe it means to find any element with an id that starts with "_foo_bar", is that right? How does this work and where is the doc for something like this?

```
$('[id*="_foo_bar"]').click...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will selects elements that have the `id` with a value containing `_foo_bar`. Its documentation is here: 
https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/